# Resque is not able to connect with postgis adapter on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgis

I have a Ruby on Rails application on heroku. We do some postgis stuff with it. According to [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis) I try to override the adapter to `postgis` when connecting to Postgresql with `ActiveRecord`. Following is in my `config/initializers/redis.rb`

```
if ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']
  $redis = Resque.redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'])
  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
        Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      config['adapter'] = 'postgis'
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    end
  end
end
```

When I enqueue a job to resque I get following warning in the logs:

`2014-10-27T19:24:35Z app[postgres.2387]: [WHITE] could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`

Which essentially [means](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#log-unexpected-eof-on-client-connection) resque crashed while connecting to the database.

My question is how can I make it work?